# Xcode 6 auto layout programmatically?

Tags: ios, xcode, layout

My problem is on this image:
[image: Screenshot]

I have this problem with Xcode 6 and I would like to know if there is a way to solve this problem programmatically... I would like to write a code which adapt my view controller to all devices... Is it possible?? 
(I already tried auto layout manually but I am really bad)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you've implemented too strict constraints. As I see on screenshot, you've probably set a strong width constraint for your buttons and inputs instead of equal widths or equal spacing between each other. Make your constrains more flexible. Prefer `>=`,`<=` constraints, equal widths constraints, leading/trailing constraints. You will need more of them in comparison to strict ones, but you'll get a true adaptive layout.

To get flexible equal spacing between views, you might find helpful a conception of spacer views. In short, place a transparent UIView and set some constraints to it. To know more, read [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutbyExample/AutoLayoutbyExample.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH5-SW7). If you like videos more (like I do :)) - watch wwdc videos, they are great. For example, [Auto Layout by Example](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/#232) or [Taking Control of Auto Layout in Xcode 5](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/#406).

As an example of equally arranged buttons take a look at this screenshot:
[image: spacer views screenshot]
This is done with a little bit complex, but understandable constraints  set:[image: constraints screenshot]

All the buttons has the equal widths constraints for each other. All spacer views has equal width constraints on each other. Each spacer view has leading/trailing constrains to buttons or parent view leadings/trailings.

With iOS 9 you have a few more options:

- instead of spacer views you can use `UILayoutGuide`
- `UIStackView` allows to achieve the same layout with no constraints at all

I suggest you to watch new WWDC 2015 videos, "Mysteries of Auto Layout",[Part1](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=218) and [Part2](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=219)

Comment: Its pretty simple with stoarybaord, but **@Pedro Costa** want to set constraints via programatically, he want to use **Visual Format Language (VFL)**

Comment: This task may be solved both in IB and in code, but strong understanding in autolayout is still required. Also, visual format language is not a silver bullet, there are many cases where you can't describe your layout via VFL completely and you still need to do some extra coding. Libraries like PureLayout may help here too.

Answer (score 0):

Hi **@Pedro Costa** its not possible here to write solution of your above problem. I am giving one *link* give some movement to study it. its too simple to understand.

May this will give you the idea how to set it.

### AutoLayout Constraints Programatically

http://www.thinkandbuild.it/learn-to-love-auto-layout-programmatically/

Home this will help.