# Buttons Constraints Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, button

I have constraints on my buttons and labels because on the new Xcode the view controller is wide for the Iphone 6 but many objects don't show up during the iOS stimulator without constraints. My question is that I have yellow triangle hazards that say that run time location of objects will be different. Would these hazards matter when I publish my app to the app store because I haven't made my developer account yet so can't try.

Comment: What kind of constraints you use? Can you  show me your screenshot on storyboard file?

Comment: I'm using horizontal center in container constraints on all my buttons and labels.Is there another way to fit all my objects on all the devices other than constraints.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can publish app to the appstore with yellow hazards in constraints, but this is not a good approach.
2. This yellow hazards means warning in your layouts and you maybe have problem with layouts in different sizes of iPhone (4, 4.5, 5.5 inches).
3. Use Size Classes in storyboards, you can preview your scenes with layout in different sizes.

Comment: I just tried running it on Iphone 5 in iOS stimulator but it cuts off the top and bottom of labels and buttons. Is there any other way than constraints. If I don't use constrainst then it doesn't work on Iphone 6.

Comment: No any other way, you need to learn constraints.

This is links to understand autolayouts:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31058385/xcode-6-auto-layout-programmatically/31059499#31059499

https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/#232 + 
https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/#228 +
https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/#406 (must see) +